# How do I resolve a "write error" installing packages on R?

Tags: r, package, installation, cran

I'm on a new office computer (Windows 10) which I've installed R3.6.1 and RStudio Desktop 1.2.5001 onto.

However I getting an error when I try and install packages, e.g.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

> Warning in install.packages :
>     write error in extracting from zip file
>
> Error in install.packages : subscript out of bounds

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies =TRUE)
```

> Warning in install.packages :
>     write error in extracting from zip file
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot open compressed file 'ps/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>
> Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Does it happen only with `ggplot2`? Can you try installing another package?

Comment: It happens with any package!

Comment: I would first suggest asking your Company IT if they have blocked installing packages from repos.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you're installing them into a folder you don't have write-access to. If you change your `.libPaths()` to install into a folder you can write to (you can probably write to a folder on your desktop, for example) the issue may be resolved.

Comment: I've tried ```.libPaths("H:/Desktop/Packages") ```

```install.packages("ggplot2", lib = "H:/Desktop/Packages")``` and still get the same error